# Use sandwich theorem to find $\lim_{x \to 0} f(x)$, when $|f(x)-1| \le x^2$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, derivatives, continuity

**My approach:**
Using the definition of absolute function we know that,

$$ 0 \le |f(x)-1| \le x^2$$

Applying $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0}$ on lower and upper bound, we get

$$ \lim_{x \to 0}\,(0)=0 \qquad\text{ and }\qquad \displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0} \, (x^2)=0$$

So, by sandwich theorem,

$$  \lim_{x \to 0} |f(x)-1|=0$$

**Case I:**

$$\lim_{x \to 0} f(x)-1=0$$

$$\implies \displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0} f(x)=1$$

**Case II:**

$$\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0} 1-f(x)=0$$

$$\implies \displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0} f(x)=1$$

In either case,
$\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0} f(x)=1$.

---

This was a 5 mark question on a test and my calculus professor gave me 2 marks for this solution. He says that he deducted marks because I wrote $0 \le |f(x)-1| \le x^2$ instead of  $-x^2 \le f(x)-1 \le x^2$ and then applying sandwich theorem.

How is my approach wrong? Will my approach yield a wrong answer in a different scenario? Please explain.

Comment: The claim that $$\lim_{x \to a} \Big( f(x) + g(x) \Big) = \lim_{x \to a} f(x) + \lim_{x \to a} g(x)$$ (here $g(x)=-1$ as a constant function) relies on the assumption that both limits, individually, exist. How do you know *a priori* that the limit for $f$ exists? You've shown that, **provided it exists**, it equals one -- but why must it exist at all?

Comment: Well, I don't have answer to this question, but since it was asked in the question, i think it is okay to assume that the limit for f exists

Comment: @OmairSiddique You do not need to assume that. Show that the limit of $f(x)$ as $x\to 0$ exists and is $1$ by using the given inequality and the definition of functional limit.

Comment: I think that it is your separation into Cases that is problematic, $f(x)-1$ might be oscillating wildly between positive and negative values; your prof's way of writing it avoids this difficulty. I certainly wouldn't have given you more than 3/5 without some explanation of what you think you're doing when you write these "cases".

Comment: @ancientmathematician does it matter if f(x)-1 is "oscillating wildly between +ve and -ve values"? I mean to say that our only concern is in the neighborhood of x=0 or at x=0, right?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean when you split into cases. The statement $\lim |f(x)-1|=0$ does not have two cases $\lim f(x)-1=0$ and $\lim 1-f(x)=0$. Until you explain exactly what you mean at this point (I don't think you can) it suggests you don't understand the definition of "limit" - I'm not your prof, but like him/her I'd not give this solution a very high score.

Comment: when i say that $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0} |f(x)-1|=0$, it implies $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0} f(x)-1=0$ when $f(x)>1$ and $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0} 1-f(x)=0$ when $f(x)<1$. What's wrong in that? I mean to ask how would one proceed from $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0} |f(x)-1|=0$

Comment: I tried to improve your typesetting but feel free to undo it for any reason. You can check a Mathjax tutorial [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33179/80734), a more complete reference can be found [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Use the continuity of the absolute value function (i.e., you can move the $\lim$ inside the absolute value): $$
0 = \lim \left| {f(x) - 1} \right| = \left| {\lim f(x) - 1} \right| \Leftrightarrow \lim f(x) = 1.
$$

Answer (score 1):

The solution is absolutely correct , no need to write   $−x^2≤f(x)−1≤x^2$ because if
$\lim_{x \to 0} |f(x)−1|=0$ then $\lim_{x \to 0} f(x)=1$ , there is no need to discuss the cases .
There is a theorem that states , if $\lim_{x \to y} |g(x)|=0$ then $\lim_{x \to y} g(x)=0$